# Entity Framework Paging Query Translation Performance Improvement

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

The way EF translates Linq query to returned paged result is as below

Linq Query : `context.Student.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Skip(10).Take(10).ToList()`

EF Translates it to : `SELECT TOP (10) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC) AS [row_number]
        FROM [dbo].[Students] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 10
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC`

For Millions Record in to the database for initial pages it takes around 2 seconds but for last pages e.g. for page number 999999 it takes more than 7 seconds, with all indexes in place.

But when I changed this translated query as below,

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
, FLOOR(row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC) /10 ) AS [page_number]
    FROM [dbo].[Students] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[page_number] = 10
ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC
```

I converted row_number to page_number using Floor function and used equal operator then I am able to load page number 999999 in around 2 seconds where as initial pages less then 1 second.

I wonder is there any way to use page_number function `FLOOR(row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC) /10 )` like I used and passing page number to load paged records.

As avoiding > symbol and using = operator has massive impact on performance of select statement.

Comment: Are you benchmarking the query running it on sql server directly or in your app? [Queries with Skip/Take overloads taking constants cannot be cached](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#4) so EF needs to retranslate the query to sql each time you invoke it, and this process can be slow.

Comment: I did benchmark on sql server directly. But I believe even time consumed by translation would be less then query performance as I said just changing query there is difference of 5 second which is huge where as translation time should be in milliseconds.